# ASP.Net MVC Kendo UI Grid draggable, how to implement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and Kendo UI. In my project I'm using kendo UI grid and need to implement the drag and drop functionality form grid to other component. Basically I've referring following example.

http://jsbin.com/itawuq/2/edit

But my grid is created in an .cshtml file in razor syntax. Not in java script or JQuery like in the example. My question is how can I bind the data source to the grid and the events and pass to controller if I initialize the grid using java script like shown in the example.

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo Beta Q1 2014 Brings a SORTABLE framework feature into the battle. Check it out [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/Beta/web/sortable/integration-grid.html).